# wpf GridViewDataColumn binding by multiple properties

Tags: wpf, binding

I am working with WPF application. I have "GridViewDataColumn" in XAML file. There is a scenario where I have to bind Invisible attribute of "GridViewDataColumn" by two properties. Please check the below code (like this)-

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="NameColumn"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsNameEnabled}"
    IsVisible="{Binding SomeColumn,Converter={StaticResource SomeBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static resources:SomeResources.Name}}"
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

But its not binding and giving some binding error. Can someone help me out how I can bind Invisible attribute by multiple properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a property twice like that. You need to use triggers instead.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="NameColumn">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Stlyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNameEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeColumn,Converter={StaticResource SomeBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static resources:SomeResources.Name}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Stlyle>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind to more than one source property, you should use a `MultiBinding` and a converter class that implements the `IMultiValueConverter` interface, e.g.:

```
public class SomeBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isNameEnabled = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        bool someColumn = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);

        //...

        return isNameEnabled && someColumn;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="NameColumn">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.IsVisible>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SomeBoolConverter}"
                      ConverterParameter="{x:Static resources:SomeResources.Name}">
            <Binding Path="IsNameEnabled" />
            <Binding Path="SomeColumn" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.IsVisible>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```